# Отображения данных в виде таблицы с помощью matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, matplotlib

Как с помощью DataFrame можно отобразить в виде таблицы в Matplotlib данные заданные в DataFrame?  При этом желательно не использовать циклы.

```
import pandas as pd 

#[[x0,y0], [x1,y1], [x2,y2], .... [xn, yn]]
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,3],[5,6],[8,1],[7,3],[3,9],[10,10]])
```

где

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем суть вопроса? Как подготовить DataFrame такой как на картинке? Или как рисовать в matplotlib таблицу как на картинке? Если вопрос в том как получить готовую картинку из DataFrame из вопроса, то это слишком общий вопрос - его следует разбить на два...

Comment: Было два подвопроса. 1) Как преобразовать исходные данные, чтобы они были приемлемы для matplotlib. 2) И как отобразить эти данные с помощью Matplotlib в том виде как я указал в виде примера (кол-во строк может быть неограниченным или большим, в одной строке может быть несколько X) ?

Comment: По правилам SO вопрос должен быть один. Вероятность того что комбинация данных вопросов будет интересна кому-то кроме вас крайне мала

Comment: Ты показал как преобразовать, осталось непонятно как отобразить.

Comment: По-моему я все понятно объяснил в комментариях...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я так понимаю, речь идёт о чем-то подобном?:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,3],[5,6],[8,1],[7,3],[3,9],[10,10]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')

plt.scatter(df[0], df[1], s=340, marker='s', color='lightgreen')
plt.scatter(df[0], df[1], s=75, marker='x', color='black')

labels = list(range(1, 11))

plt.xticks(np.arange(.5, 11.5), labels)
plt.yticks(np.arange(.5, 11.5), labels)

ax.invert_yaxis()

plt.rcParams['xtick.bottom'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labelbottom'] = False
plt.rcParams['xtick.top'] = plt.rcParams['xtick.labeltop'] = True

ax.grid(which='major')
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Красивое решение!

Answer (score 5):

Если вопрос в том как получить DataFrame с данными как на картинке, то это можно сделать так:

Исходный DF:

```
In [107]: df
Out[107]:
    0   1
0   1   2
1   2   3
2   5   6
3   8   1
4   7   3
5   3   9
6  10  10
```

Решение:

```
In [108]: res = (df.rename(columns={0:"y", 1:"x"})
                   .assign(v=1)
                   .pivot_table(index="x", columns="y", values="v")
                   .fillna("")
                   .replace(1, "X")
                   .rename_axis(None, axis=0)
                   .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
```

Результат:

```
In [109]: res
Out[109]:
    1  2  3  5  7  8  10
1                  X
2   X
3      X        X
6            X
9         X
10                    X
```